# How to add LocalStorage to buttons to change colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I'm having trouble adding LocalStorage to the buttons to change as cores, new in javascript and we want to implement this function on my personal blog.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".header--theme-button").on("click", function() {
  var primaryColor = localStorage.getItem("--theme-primary");
  var secondaryColor = localStorage.getItem("--theme-primary");

  var primaryColor = $(this).css("--theme-primary");
  var secondaryColor = $(this).css("--theme-secondary");


  $().change(function () {
    var primaryColor = $(this).val();
    $('.header--theme-button').css("--theme-primary");
    localStorage.setItem("--theme-primary", primaryColor);
    var secondaryColor = $(this).val();
    $('.header--theme-button').css("--theme-secondary");
    localStorage.setItem("--theme-primary", secondaryColor);
  });

  $(".header--theme-button").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(document.body).css("--primary-color", primaryColor);
  $(document.body).css("--secondary-color", secondaryColor);
});

});
```

HTML: https://pastebin.com/KswauZRU

CSS: https://pastebin.com/85bH2J5w

Comment: its kinda hard to add the localStorage to the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.
There were some errors in the code. Mainly you were overwriting `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor`

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var primaryColor = localStorage.getItem("--primary-color");
  console.log("localstorage primary: " + localStorage.getItem("--primary-color"));
  $(document.body).css("--primary-color", primaryColor);

  var secondaryColor = localStorage.getItem("secondary");
  console.log("localstorage secondary: " + localStorage.getItem("--secondary-color"));
  $(document.body).css("--secondary-color", secondaryColor);

  $( ".header--theme-button" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).css("--theme-primary")==primaryColor){
      console.log("found active element: "+primaryColor);
      $(".header--theme-button").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
  });

  $(".header--theme-button").on("click", function() {

     $(".header--theme-button").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");

     var primaryColor = $('.active').css("--theme-primary");
     console.log("primaryColor: " + primaryColor);
     localStorage.setItem("--primary-color", primaryColor);
     $(document.body).css("--primary-color", primaryColor);

     var secondaryColor = $('.active').css("--theme-secondary");
     console.log("secondaryColor: " + secondaryColor);
     localStorage.setItem("--secondary-color", secondaryColor);
     $(document.body).css("--secondary-color", secondaryColor);
   });
 });
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pauloco/qhjdwzr5/37/) (because the native stackoverflow inline snippet did not work) so you can see directly that it works there. By pressing the "run" button top left you reload the code and see that the old color stays.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: How do I save the button that was active? https://imgur.com/VhFB1d4

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pauloco/qhjdwzr5/37/ include this at the end of the ready-function
    $( ".header--theme-button" ).each(function() {
     if($(this).css("--theme-primary")==primaryColor){
       console.log("found");
        $(".header--theme-button").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
  });

Comment: By the way: did you remove the accepted answer tag? I also added this code to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I removed it because I thought the topic would close and there would be no more answers, I am new to the forum.

Comment: Sure! No big thing. But the posts stay forever (unless somebody deletes them by hand). And thus it is helpful to upvote answers and questions and also to mark them as accepted answer. So others with a similar question and search engines find the solution. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".header--theme-button").on("click", function() {


  var primaryColor = localStorage.getItem("tema");
  var secondaryColor = localStorage.getItem("tema2");
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("tema"));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("tema2"));

  // var primaryColor = $(this).css("--theme-primary");
  // console.log(this);
  // var secondaryColor = $(this).css("--theme-secondary");





  $(".header--theme-button").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(document.body).css("--primary-color", primaryColor);
  $(document.body).css("--secondary-color", secondaryColor);

  var primaryColor = $('.active').css("--theme-primary");
  localStorage.setItem("tema", primaryColor);
  console.log(primaryColor);
  console.log(localStorage.setItem($('--theme-primary'), primaryColor));
  var secondaryColor = $('.active').css("--theme-secondary");
  localStorage.setItem("tema2", secondaryColor);
  console.log(primaryColor);
  console.log(secondaryColor);

});




});
```

Hi! Try this! Now he remember the last choice

Comment: Still not saving to local storage